# Will transfers mess up my GTA character?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I have GTA 5 on PS4 but my friend has it on PS3. He wants me to play with him, can I still play my character that I transferred to my PS4 on my PS3? Or will it mess something up?

Answer (score 1):

This link has some info on character transfers: [Rockstar platform character transfers](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/202892778-Transferring-Your-Previous-Grand-Theft-Auto-Online-Characters-and-Progression-to-PlayStation-4-Xbox-One-or-PC)

From that info, it sounds like you'll be able to play with your pre-transfer data on your ps3, without affecting your ps4 character. It does say you can only transfer from ps3 to ps4 once though, so you won't be able to import any progress with your friend to your ps4 later (if you wanted to).